# Los objetos agregados en la base de datos no se muestran en la tabla Treeview de TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, mysqldb

Estoy trabajando en Python con una base de datos creada en `DB Browser`, ya creé una una tabla con `treeview` pero los productos que agrego mediante la función `Agregar_producto()` no se listan en la tabla:

```
btnAgregar = Button(frame1, text = "Guardar", bg = "light blue", state = 'normal', command =lambda:Agregar_producto())
btnAgregar.place(x = 45, y = 90, width = "100", height = "30")
mensaje = Label(frame1, text = '', fg = 'Red', font= ("Roboto", 8))
mensaje.place(x = 10, y = 75)

tree = ttk.Treeview(ventana, columns = 2)
tree.place(x = 670, y = 190, width = "300", height = "200")
lambda:Obtener_productos()

def run_query(query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(nombre_DB) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        resultado = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return resultado
def validacion():
global concepto, importe
return len(concepto.get()) != 0 and len(importe.get()) != 0
def Agregar_producto():
    if validacion():
        query = 'INSERT INTO Productos VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)'
        parameters = (concepto.get(), importe.get())
        run_query(query, parameters)
        mensaje['text'] = 'Concepto {} fue adherido exitosamente!!!'.format(concepto.get())
        concepto.delete(0, END)
        importe.delete(0, END)
    else:
        mensaje['text'] = 'Concepto e Importe son requeridos!!!'
        Obtener_productos()
```

Comment: Hiciste commit al añadir las cosas (o hay autocommit habilitado)?

Comment: Lo hice al añadir los productos o esa era al menos mi idea.